# Multiple button handling in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, button

I have six buttons

[image]

when one of the button is clicked take an animation . so i will give it an animate atrribute (will be large in scale when clicked) to do this .

so , if i give to all of the button an animation , when a button clicked it must the other button back to there postion . acctually just one button be activate in
one time .
Code :

```
btn1 = findviewby<Button>(R.id.btn1)
btn2 = findviewby<Button>(R.id.btn2)
btn3 = findviewby<Button>(R.id.btn3)
btn4 = findviewby<Button>(R.id.btn4)
btn5 = findviewby<Button>(R.id.btn5)
btn6 = findviewby<Button>(R.id.btn6)

   btn1.setOnClickListener {


            btn1.animate()
                .scaleXBy(0.1f)
                .scaleYBy(0.1f)
                .duration = 200

     // and if the other btn's (btn2 , 3 , 4, 5 , 6) is get animation already go back on there position

        }
```

if i do above code for each btn the all of them take animation and will be active and this not right .

I want when a btn clicked the other btn back on there position

thank's in advanced

Comment: can you describe more about your problem, it is not clear

Comment: i will edit my question .

Comment: As if I understood  correctly, you have 6 buttons, when you click 1 button it will go translate animation on it. Suppose if you click another button it has to translate with animation and the previous button animation translation need to be reset so that at a time one button should be bigger. Same thing repeat for all the buttons. Rite?

Comment: yes bro . exactly true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Out of a group of buttons, at a time only one button will be translated to given x, y rest of the buttons will be reset to original position if already translated.

activity_buttons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ButtonsActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="149dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ButtonsActivity.kt

```
class ButtonsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val buttonList = mutableListOf<Button>()
var activatedButtonIndex = -1

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buttons)

    val button1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
    val button4 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
    val button5 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)

    button1.setOnClickListener(listener)
    button2.setOnClickListener(listener)
    button3.setOnClickListener(listener)
    button4.setOnClickListener(listener)
    button5.setOnClickListener(listener)

    //set tags for dynamically identify the object in foreach instead of resource id
    button1.tag = 0
    button2.tag = 1
    button3.tag = 2
    button4.tag = 3
    button5.tag = 4
    buttonList.add(button1)
    buttonList.add(button2)
    buttonList.add(button3)
    buttonList.add(button4)
    buttonList.add(button5)
}


private val listener = View.OnClickListener { view ->
    val tag: Int = view.tag as Int
    view?.let {
        if (activatedButtonIndex == tag) {
            return@let
        }
        startTranslateAnim(it)
        if (activatedButtonIndex != tag) {
            resetTranslationAnim(activatedButtonIndex)
        }
        activatedButtonIndex = tag
    }
}

private fun startTranslateAnim(it: View) {
    it.animate()
        .scaleXBy(0.1f)
        .scaleYBy(0.1f)
        .duration = 200
}

private fun resetTranslationAnim(previousSelectedIndex: Int) {
    buttonList?.let {
        it.forEachIndexed { index, button ->
            if (index == previousSelectedIndex)
                button.animate().scaleXBy(-0.1f)
                    .scaleYBy(-0.1f)
                    .duration = 200
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it worked . thank's body ... but for me as a new developer is little bit hard to understand whats going on exactly ...